# how to recognize numbers in a name of redomforest fomula?

Tags: r, random-forest

I have several RandomForest formulas named forest.1, forest.2, forest.3, etc. Would like to read them one by one using "for" iterations, for example:

```
for(i in 1:20){
   model = forest.i
   predict.y = predict(model, test.x)
}
```

Of course, forest.i (i from 1 to 20) cannot be recognized as 20 fomulas. What can I do to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270482/string-to-variable-name-in-r

Answer (score 2):

You can use function `get`, e.g. `model <- get(sprintf("forest.%i", i))`. This will create a string, e.g `forest.1` and try to fetch an object with this name.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them into a list first:

```
forests <- list(
  forest.1,
  forest.2,
  forest.3,
  ...,
  forest.20
)
```

(Fill in the dots.) Then, you can simply do

```
for (model in forests) {
  ... # your code
}
```

If you don't want to type the 20 list entries, create a character vector with the values `"forest.1"` till `"forest.20"` and use [`mget`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.3.1/topics/get).